# Handle back button, in MonoGame on Android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, back-button, monogame

i have a problem with handling back button in my game on android, developed on MonoGame with MonoDroid. I can't catch back button click event.

I tried:

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    LoadingScreen.Load(ScreenManager, true, null, new BackgroundScreen(),
                               new LevelSelectScreen());
}
```

And on main Activity

```
    public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            ...
            return true;
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        ...
        Toast.MakeText(this, keyCode + " key! + " + keyCode.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back)
        {
            ...
            return true;
        }

        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Nothing helps, on WP first variant works perfectly

Comment: I can't catch back button click event.

Comment: As far as I am aware GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back is the way to do it so maybe there is something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEAH!
I found solution:
When you call

```
GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One)
```

in Android GamePadState cleared

```
public static GamePadState GetState(PlayerIndex playerIndex)
{
    var instance = GamePad.Instance;
    var state = new GamePadState(new GamePadThumbSticks(), new GamePadTriggers(), new GamePadButtons((Buttons)instance._buttons), new GamePadDPad());
    instance.Reset(); // <- CLEAR BUTTONS
    return state;
}
```

So, do not call GetState in Android several times.